# Access a UserControl property from another UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I created a UserControl, which has a property called `Hero`

```
public partial class UcHeros : UserControl
{
    public UcHeros()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Hero = "Spiderman";
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeroProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Hero", typeof(string), typeof(UcHeros), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Hero
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeroProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeroProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I'm using this UserControl inside a Window like this :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <wpfApplication1:UcHeros x:Name="Superhero" />    
            <Button Click="OnClick">Click</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now to get the Hero value I use this :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HumanProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Human", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Human
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HumanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HumanProperty, value); }
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Superhero.Hero); 
    }
}
```

I can access to the **Hero** because I gived a name to that UserControl in my XAML declaration `x:Name="Superhero"`, but how can I access to that value if I remove the Name property ?

I mean : How can I store the `Hero` value in the `Human` value using some sort of Binding !

Comment: Yes this is MVVM sir, and the Click event is just a sample test I could use an ICommand instead

Comment: No, it is not. You are using an event handler and putting this in the code behind. This breaks the supposed MVVM pattern.

Comment: WTF, I'm telling you this is just a sample code. the real code uses a RelayCommand with the Button so yes this is MVVM. Can you answer the question now ?

Comment: LOL Sorry, I did not read you comment properly. The reason for the null reference exception is clearly because you are initalising your DP to null with `new PropertyMetadata(null)`. Initalise it to something and the null reference should go away and Sheridan's answer should work. I actually use a Mediator for all cross control updates of properties. It is much cleaner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `Bind` your `Human` property to the `Hero` property on your control:

```
<wpfApplication1:UcHeros Hero="{Binding Human, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Try using a `OneWayToSource Binding` if you just want to read the value and not update it.

---

UPDATE >>>

As @Killercam suggested, try setting the default value for your property in the declaration instead of the constructor:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeroProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("Hero", typeof(string), typeof(UcHeros), 
    new PropertyMetadata("Spiderman"));
```

If that still doesn't work, then you've got something else going on there.

Comment: I already tried that <wpfApplication1:UcHeros Hero="{Binding Human}" />, but it gives me NullReferenceException ?

Comment: What element is `null`? Where did you declare your 'extra' property? Please show your `UserControl` XAML too.

Comment: There is no XAML code in my `UcHeros` and Human was already declared in my code behind of `MainWindow`. Both are Null because when you do `Hero="{Binding Human}` the Hero property bind itself to Human which is null !